# How to build custom preference extend android.support.v7.preference library?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

In these days i'm working on an app which is contain preference and i tried to put each preferences into a CardView. I can make a custom preference with old version of preference library but when i want to use CardView, I have to use preference library v7.
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcSOP.jpg)
As you can see, I made a preference category with CardView. Firstly I made a preference activity with a CardView which is contain a fragment. then i add my preference files in my ActivityPrefrences

```
public class ActivityPrefrences extends AppCompatActivity {

private int[] prefResId = {R.xml.app_preferences,R.xml.app_preferences};
private int[] fragmentResId = {R.id.fragmentGeneralSetting,R.id.fragmentRtl};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preference);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        for(int i=0;i<prefResId.length;i++){
            Fragment fragment = new PreferenceDataFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("PREFERENCE_KEY", prefResId[i]);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(fragmentResId[i],fragment).commit();
        }

    }
}
```

Fragment Class:

```
public class PreferenceDataFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    //getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("settings");
    //getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesMode(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        int resId = bundle.getInt("PREFERENCE_KEY", R.xml.app_preferences);
        addPreferencesFromResource(resId);
    }
  }
}
```

activity_preference.xml

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_thumb"
    android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_track"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:duplicateParentState="false"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragmentGeneralSetting"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragmentRtl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Finally i added my own Custom preference in preference.xml but when i loading this activity on phone, i miss a part of view on screen. as you can see on above image, Gray area is holder and white are is a part of custom preference view. 

Now i can't understand why my custom view not fitting in whole area of holder? and i can't use setSummary and setTitle in class, Actually "title" and "summary" not applied on TextViews, I don't know why?

This is my custom preference class

```
public class RTLCheckBoxPreference extends Preference {

private OnPreferenceClickListener prefListener;
private boolean currentValue = false;

public RTLCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public RTLCheckBoxPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                             int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.prefrence_checkbox);
}

@Override
protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue, Object defaultValue) {
    super.onSetInitialValue(restorePersistedValue, defaultValue);
    currentValue = restorePersistedValue ? getPersistedBoolean(false):(Boolean) defaultValue;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    holder.itemView.setClickable(false);
    holder.itemView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

    RecyclerView.LayoutParams param = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    param.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(param);
  }
}
```

This is my custom layout for my prefrence.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
              android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
              android:focusable="true" >

    <com.bvapp.widget.HoloButton.HoloButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCheckBoxPrefrence"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/check_box_outline_blank"
            android:id="@+id/imgCheckBoxPrefrence"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/title"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                  android:textColor="@color/text_main"
                  android:ellipsize="marquee"
                  android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                  android:gravity="right"
                  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                  android:textSize="@dimen/font_norm_size"/>

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/summary"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
                  android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/title"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                  android:textColor="@color/text_aux"
                  android:maxLines="4"
                  android:gravity="right"
                  android:textSize="@dimen/font_aux_norm_size"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I tried a lot to find my answers, even i tried to set padding and margin to "0" but it's not working. How should I fit my own custom preference in holder and use "title" and "summary" in my custom preferences?